# Google Analytics Custom Variables per click instead of per session

Tags: android, ios, session, google-analytics

On the web and in mobile we use custom variables to track various attributes of our search such as property type and location.

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-3401544-1']);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 3, 'PropertyClassID', '1', 3]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 4, 'LocalityID', '2168', 3]);
_gaq.push(['_setCustomVar', 5, 'IsMobileSite', 'False', 3]);
_gaq.push(['_setDomainName', 'myhome.ie']);
_gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
```

On the web the user session is managed by the cookie's issued to the client so the user session is counted correctly. On mobile we are using the same method:

```
tracker.Set (GAIConstants.SessionControl, "start");
tracker.Set (GAIConstants.ScreenName, "SearchResultsView");
tracker.Set (GAIFields.CustomDimension (2), googleLocalityID);
tracker.Set (GAIFields.CustomDimension (3), googlePropertyClass);
tracker.Set (GAIFields.CustomDimension (5), googleRegionID);
tracker.Send (GAIDictionaryBuilder.CreateAppView().Build());
```

The problem we are having is that we are having to set the start on the session control with every screen to get the custom dimensions registered but it starts a new session which makes out session count for mobile massively skewed. Is it possible to achieve the registration of the custom variables while correcting the session count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In your first example for web tracking using ga.js, you set the scope of the Custom Variables to [page/hit-level](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiBasicConfiguration#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCustomVar) (that is what the last argument, 3, is referring to). For mobile you would have had to create Custom Dimensions using the [Google Analytics admin interface](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709829) and that is where you set the scope for the dimension. So first make sure the scope of those custom dimensions is set to Hit.

2) I'm not sure why you think you need to start a new session. If you have hit level custom dimensions, just set them and send with the appView as described in the [Custom Dimensions and Metrics Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/customdimsmets).